# Storing Auth0 User Information in Angular Service

Tags: angular, auth0

I am using Auth0 with Angular and I have followed their quick start tutorial. All is working fine. However, I'm fairly new to Angular and to Auth0 and I am struggling a little bit to work effectively with the observables. The service that I have created is here https://gist.github.com/infornite/557ad3406bda45c6183c12048a6f659e

When I want to check if the user is logged in I am doing the following:

```
this.auth.isAuthenticated$.subscribe(isAuth=>{
  if(isAuth){
    //Do something because the user is authenticated
  }
})
```

If I want to access the details of the token (for example permissions are stored on the token) I do the following:

```
if (this.auth.isAuthenticated$) {
      this.auth.getTokenSilently$()
        .subscribe((token) => {
          let dc = this.decodeAccessToken(token)
               this.authDetails.roles = dc['permissions']
        })
    }
```

It all works quiet well but it seems like a lot of overhead each time I want to access some info from the current user. I thought to write the information to localstorage but I'm not sure of the security implications.

Is there a way that I can store the info when the user is authenticated or logs in again and just access it when I need to. I'd like to do this from within the auth service so I can just have a userRoles[] as a value and then request authservice.userRoles whenever I need it without needing to go through the getTokeSilently part each time.